# How to get out a certain field value from a object from a array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm learning firebase cloud functions with JavaScript,

I get a QuerySnapshot back of a collection of documents each document holds an ID field and a message field.

Where I'm stuck now is that every time I loop through the collection I want to be able to just take the ID field out from each object and save it.

I've tried all the ways that I can think of that come up on Google and stack overflow none are working for me, I'm obviously doing something wrong.

I'm totally new to JavaScript so this may be an easy fix if anyone has any information

This is my code in visual studio that I'm using, which is working fine from where I can see to get to the collection that I need to

```
// onDelete is my trigger which would then go and fetch the collection that I want 

exports.onDelet = functions.firestore.document('recentMsg/currentuid/touid/{documentId}').onDelete(async(snap, context) => {
const data = snap.data();
const contex = context.params;

// once I get the information from onDelete the following code starts

await admin.firestore().collection(`messages/currentuid/${contex.documentId}`)
.get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    //this array will hold all documents from the collection
      const results = []
    const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
         id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
    }));

    results.push(data)
    console.log(results)

     //This is one of the ways I've tried 
    //results.forEach((doc) => { 
   //console.log(doc.id)
  //this is a print out in the terminal
 // >  undefined
// } );

});
```

Below is a print out that I get in terminal which is all the information that it holds which is great,
But really all I want is to have an array that holds every id
if there was just one value in the array I know this would not be a problem but because there is an object with multiple values that's the issue.

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "onDelet"
>  [
>    [
>      { id: '28ZyROMQkzEBBDwTm6yV', msg: 'sam 2' },
>      { id: 'ixqgYqmwlZJfb5D9h8WV', msg: 'sam 3' },
>      { id: 'lLyNDLLIHKc8hCnV0Cgc', msg: 'sam 1' }
>    ]
>  ]
i  functions: Finished "onDelet" in ~1s
```

once again apologies if this is a dumb question I'm a newbie.

Comment: Would like to know what is the problem with this `const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
         id: doc.id
    }));`

Comment: @Umer Malik , `results.push(data)` is unnecessary, `data` is array of data, comment that and your commented snippet should work

Comment: Your data is returned array. The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results.

Answer (score 0):

With `await admin.firestore().collection(`messages/currentuid/${contex.documentId}`) .get()` you get a `QuerySnapshot` that supports `forEach` and not `map`. Just write your code like this:

```js
// onDelete is my trigger which would then go and fetch the collection that I want 

exports.onDelet = functions.firestore.document('recentMsg/currentuid/touid/{documentId}').onDelete(async(snap, context) => {
const data = snap.data();
const contex = context.params;

// once I get the information from onDelete the following code starts

await admin.firestore().collection(`messages/currentuid/${contex.documentId}`)
.get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    //this array will hold all documents from the collection
      const results = []
    
    snapshot.forEach((doc) =>{
      results.push({id:doc.id,...doc.data()})
    });

    console.log(results)

     //This is one of the ways I've tried 
    //results.forEach((doc) => { 
   //console.log(doc.id)
  //this is a print out in the terminal
 // >  undefined
// } );

});
```

I assume that `messages/currentuid/${contex.documentId}` is a collecion and not a single document.

You can read more baout it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-v8_3).

Comment: yes its a collection, thanks for the help I see what you mean after I used your code works the same